# column names when using `as.data.frame` over nested list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Assuming we have a nested list `lst` like below

```
lst <- list(
  A = list(a.x = 1:5, a.y = 6:10),
  B = list(b.x = -(1:5), b.y = -(6:10), b.z = -(11:15))
)

> lst
$A
$A$a.x
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$A$a.y
[1]  6  7  8  9 10


$B
$B$b.x
[1] -1 -2 -3 -4 -5

$B$b.y
[1]  -6  -7  -8  -9 -10

$B$b.z
[1] -11 -12 -13 -14 -15
```

When I use `df <- as.data.frame(lst)`, we get

```
> df
  A.a.x A.a.y B.b.x B.b.y B.b.z
1     1     6    -1    -6   -11
2     2     7    -2    -7   -12
3     3     8    -3    -8   -13
4     4     9    -4    -9   -14
5     5    10    -5   -10   -15
```

As you can see, the names of different layers of `lst` are concatenated by `.` to produce the column names, e.g., `A.a.x`. Since I already have `.` in the deeper layer of `lst`, e.g., `a.x`, the column name like `A.a.x` looks a bit confusing.

I am wondering if `.` is the default connecting symbol when using `as.data.frame` over `list`. Otherwise, is there any optional argument that allows users define their own symbol (instead of `.`) when using `as.data.frame`?

Comment: It could be related to `make.names` being ccalled in `as.data.frame`, which calls `make.unique` and make.unique is `function (names, sep = ".")`

Comment: @akrun Thanks for your comment! It seems `make.names` affects row names rather than column names. Do you have a solution to address the issue?

Comment: If you check the `as.data.frame.list` source code, this seems to happen in the last line `do.call(data.frame`, and then you may have check the `data.frame` source code.  There are several places, `make.unique` is called.

Comment: Thomas, as @akrun says, if you track the code through, we come to `data.frame`, though the problem does not lie in `make.names` or `make.unique`. If you have a nested list passed to `data.frame` you are going to branch to the line `else paste(vnames[[i]], namesi, sep = ".")` (which is line 67 of the function body).  This takes a data frame that has already been created from your nested vectors and pastes the name of the parent element on its column names. So unfortunately this is hard coded into `data.frame`. Your best bet is your own custom naming wrapper.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks, now I see what happens there.

Answer (score 3):

As a follow-up to akrun's excellent answer, here's a simple wrapper you can use to specify the separator:

```r
as_data_frame <- function(lst, sep = ".")
{
   setNames(as.data.frame(lst),
   unlist(mapply(function(x, y) paste(x, y, sep = sep), 
                 names(lst), lapply(lst, names))))
}
```

So you can have:

```
as_data_frame(lst, "->")
#>   A->a.x A->a.y B->b.x B->b.y B->b.z
#> 1      1      6     -1     -6    -11
#> 2      2      7     -2     -7    -12
#> 3      3      8     -3     -8    -13
#> 4      4      9     -4     -9    -14
#> 5      5     10     -5    -10    -15
```

Answer (score 2):

The line that changes the name is line no: 68 in `data.frame`

```
paste(vnames[[i]], namesi, sep = ".")
```

---

If we use some `print` statements, it becomes clear.  As the `sep` is hardcoded, it can be changed only if we change the `body` of the function

```
do.call(f2, lst)
#[1] "before change"
#[1] "A"
#[1] "A"
#[1] "after change"
#[1] "A.a.x" "A.a.y"
#[1] "before change"
#[1] "B"
#[1] "B"
#[1] "after change"
#[1] "B.b.x" "B.b.y" "B.b.z"
```

where 'f2' is the changed function with `print` statements